# Can I pass a linked list from a C# Web Service to a JavaScript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, linked-list

**I've created a linked list class** in my JavaScript code and then translated that code into C#.

Right now I have a JavaScript function that calls a Web Service in order to get an array of names, the JavaScript `onComplete` function then takes that array and makes it into a linked list.

Is there any way I can create the linked list in the Web Service and pass it back to be used by the JavaScript code or can linked lists not transfer properly?

**Edit:** Let me rephrase my question to something that makes a little more sense. If you have a custom made object created by a class say.... class User, and that class has a variable called user name. If you pass a User object: objUser, back from C# to JavaScript, how does the JavaScript know it can access `objUser.userName`? What about possible methods it can invoke on this user object?

Comment: There's no such thing as a linked list. There is only your JavaScript code that creates something you call a "linked list". What makes you think your "linked list" can't transfer properly? Did you try it and fail? What did you try? How did it fail? What does your "linked list" look like?

Comment: @Matt: Google "JSON". BTW, have you seriously used JavaScript and web services for more than a week, and not heard about JSON?

Comment: @Matt: Arrays in JavaScript are actually "documented". They are even mentioned in some "books". They're not among the more advanced features, either.

Comment: @Matt: here to get help: but what was the problem? That you needed to get linked lists to a web service, or that you don't know JavaScript 101?

Comment: @Matt: I suppose the world is a stranger place than I know, but I had an awful hard time imagining a place on Earth where anyone working both with JavaSript and Web Services had not heard of JSON, or even seen the word written. I try not to assume much, but must we truly assume nothing at all?

Comment: @Matt: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json

Comment: @John  - Just from casual reading you seem really hostile to this guy.  So what - the dude hasn't heard of JSON.  Maybe comment "Can you elucidate?" is better, or ignore the question.

Comment: @David: not so much hostile, as disbelieving. You learn something new every day, and what I learned today is that it's possible to work with JavaScript and Web Services and not know about JSON, or the Array class in JavaScript. Increasingly, I don't know how to help people who learned at random. How to tell from the question what it is that Matt actually needs?

Comment: @John:  2nded David's comment.  Chill your socks MVP ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar question when I was creating my ASP.NET MVC application. Basically the answer is that JavaScript does not have the same concept of Types as in C#.

Let's say that you've decided to use JSON to pass data between your client and server in your application. The choice of JSON, XML, YAML or other format is not important.

**Server Side**

On your server side, in your C# code, you can do something like this (assuming you are using a JSON library of some sort):

```
var myLinkedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LinkedList>(json);
```

Now you've got a myLinkedList variable of Type LinkedList. myLinkedList now behaves like all LinkedList instances.

**Client Side**

However on the client site, in your JavaScript code, you probably do something like this:

```
function LinkedList(){
    //Constructor for your LinkedList
};

LinkedList.prototype = {
    //Various functions to operate on your linked list
};
```

You need to write something like this to deserialize the data that returns from the server:

```
var linkedList = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Note that there is NO WAY to indicate that you want this deserialized data to go into the LinkedList "class" that you've defined earlier. JavaScript does not understand that LinkedList is a "class" that you've added functionality to using prototype.

What you get back is a JavaScript object.

One way to get around this is to do something like this:

```
var linkedList = new LinkedList();
var deserializedObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

linkedList.Items = deserializedObject.Items;
```

Basically, you'd have to copy over all the state from your deserialized object into your linkedList variable.

Comment: JSON stands for "Javascript Object Notation" and is a data format for exchanging objects between JavaScript and your back end code and vice versa.

Use a library like JSON.NET in your C# code and a parsing library like that found on www.json.org to work with JSON in your code.